# what's the meaning of double underscore ($_.value__)?

Tags: powershell

Today on powershell.com

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/04/26/dump-enumerations.aspx

I've found this tip

```
function Get-Enum($name){
        [Enum]::GetValues($name) | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$_}},@{n="Value";e={$_.value__}} |
        format-table -autosize
    }
```

Can someone explain me what's the meaning of `$_.value__` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say this is kind of a hacky way to get the underling value of a enum. Here is the related question and answer:
[What is the purpose of the public "value__" field that I can see in Reflector against my enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214031/323582)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had difficults too to find anything using google. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just another property returned by GetValues().