# in visual studio 2015 what does {enum}.value_ mean?

Tags: .net, enums, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed visual studio 2015 (previously on 2012), and when I use an `Enum` (instantiated or otherwise) in either `VB.NET` or `C#`, as well as the `Enum` members I also have the option of `value__`, an `Integer`.

What does this option do?

[image]

--Edit--
In this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081668/what-is-value-defined-in-enum-in-c-sharp), it says that

> " I found that value__ is just a special instance field used by the
>   enum to hold the value of the selected member"

Could you explain what that means in practice? In my second example above, what would "value__" tell me for `test`? would it just be the underlying number for the enum value? Why is this now accessible in VS2015? Is that true for me or for everyone?

Comment: It is odd that shows up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is value\_\_ defined in Enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081668/what-is-value-defined-in-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores the enumeration value for the compiler to use (see [What is the purpose of the public "value__" field that I can see in Reflector against my enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214031/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-public-value-field-that-i-can-see-in-reflector-ag)) - the fact that it is visible in VS is probably a bug - it disappears in later releases.